# Mongoose opposite populate an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, virtual, populate

A list could have many items. I can easily retrieve all the items from a list but I'm having issues doing the opposite i.e retrieving all lists which contain an item

ItemSchema:

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, min: 1 },
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
},{ toJSON: { virtuals: true }});
```

ListSchema:

```
const ListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  items: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Item', quantity: 'String'
  }],
  completed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

Document:

```
"items": [
    {
       "_id": "5c6d74a98a3f532b4c1d2a23",
       "quantity": "7"
    }
],
```

How I populate: `Item.findById(id).populate('lists');` but it returns empty array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used MongoDB in a long time, but it doesn't seem you have "lists" key in your Item Schema to populate in the first place. Maybe you should add one or query the lists that have that item.

Comment: I forgot to add the virtual schema to the first post... that's how I managed to do the opposite populate but to another model. This time though I don't have just an ID, I have an array of IDs and quantity.